# Refactored "MySettings" to "Settings" on accident. Cannot revert back to normal

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I was trying to troubleshoot why my default settings. Settings values weren't updating. Visual Studio showed me a recommended fix of refactoring "MySettings" to "Settings" and now every reference to My.Settings is broken and the word settings has turned green (used to be white).

I tried just hitting the undo button, and then closing without saving. But it didn't fix anything. Makes me think it isn't a project issue but a `VS2016` issue.

```
My.Settings.ActiveDrive = My.Settings.Default.ActiveDrive
My.Settings.Save()
```

This is the code I was altering. I was trying to error proof my code and reset the value to the default to simulate a new user with no saved settings yet. Then I switched Settings to MySettings to see if that'd do anything and VS asked if I wanted to refactor MySettings to just Settings. I said yes... And now the code is broken.

I just want Settings to go back to normal. The way it worked before I hit "refactor MySettings".

Comment: Update: It is not a VS2016 issue. I opened a new project and My.Settings works fine. The "Settings" that is normally a "read only property" has been changed to a "class". And I cannot for the life of me figure out how to change it back to normal...

Comment: Do a 'Find in Files' for "MySettings" in the new project and then look for the same locations in the other project and change it back by hand.

Comment: By the way, I'm fairly sure that there's no such thing as VS2016.  There was 2015 and 2017 and now there's 2019 too.

Comment: That's actually what I ended up doing. Found the issue in the settings.designer.vb file.

Comment: Oh yea I just checked, its VS 2017. I had Office 2016 so just assumed it would be the same year. Guess I was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually able to figure it out.

For anyone out there that runs into this issue in the future (Since I found 0 results on google about this), you simply go to your solution explorer in the top right, click the drop down icon next to Settings.settings, double click on Settings.Designer.vb, ctrl+f and search for "settings" and rename any class designated "Settings" result back to "MySettings". Don't rename the other "Settings" appearances otherwise it'll break again.

Then your code will go back to having a read-only "settings" option and a class option called "MySettings".